# Meaning of 'You're mine' in this situation

Tags: meaning

I'm studying english using American comic.

[image: situation]

In above situation, this weird man says `You're mine now!!!`
I don't understand this meaning.
It's similar to `Gotcha`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something is **yours**, or you say that it is **mine**, it means that you possess it or own it; it belongs to you and  you therefore have control over it.

**gotcha** is a phonetic spelling of how many people pronounce "got you", which means "I have you", and *have* is a synonym of "possess" or "hold". **Gotcha!** is an exclamation which is used to mean "I have managed to catch (or to trap) you!"

Since you can have something that does not belong to you, **gotcha** and **you're mine** are not perfectly synonymous.  The former means "I have you" and the latter means "I own you".